# setting Ctrl+L for selecting line in VS Code Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code for a while and I get used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut to select a line in VS Code. but this shortcut doesn't work in VS Code Jupyter notebooks! how can I add this shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**

Then search 'Ctrl + L' , right-click the unwanted item, and select **remove keybinding**

[image]